# Tabs in react not displaying appropriate content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui

I am using the `Tab` from semantic-ui-react. I need to display a list of days and their corresponding events for that day. However, an event created in one day shows up in the other day too.

[image]

[image]

As seen, I created an event in day 1, but it shows up in day 2, which is incorrect. Here's how I generate the tab data:

```
const panes = selectedDays.map((day, index) => {
  const count = index + 1;
  return {
    menuItem: `Day ${count}`,
    render: () => <Tab.Pane><Agenda day={day} index={count} /></Tab.Pane>
  };
});
this.setState({ panes });
```

Component Code

```
{
            currentIndex === 3 &&
            <Fragment>
              <Tab
                menu={{ pointing: true }}
                panes={this.state.panes}
              />
              <Button className='formnext' onClick={this.handlePrevious}>
                <FontAwesome name='angle-left' style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: '2.2rem' }} className='logout' />
              </Button>
              <Button className='formnext' onClick={this.handleNext}>
                <FontAwesome name='angle-right' style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: '2.2rem' }} className='logout' />
              </Button>
            </Fragment>
          }
```

If I add a `key` attribute to the `Tab.Pane` or `Agenda` component, clicking on a tab header, just clears my state and I am left with no data. Any idea how to solve this one?

Comment: Can you please let me know why have you taken render as a key? Can you try changinf it, and please add the whole component in which you are using this, so that anybody can understand the case scenario.

Comment: @SuryaPurohit I have taken `render` as a key because the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab) say to do so. Updated the question to include the component code also.